# Error screen while updating from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 20.10. How can we recover data and repair the installation?

Tags: boot, data-recovery

[image]

I was updating Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 20.10 and an error message displayed. How can we recover data and repair the installation? (I remember there was safe mode in Windows but is there something that can be done in Ubuntu.) Even after restarting this screen is only coming. How can I proceed?

I am posting this message from mobile phone. I request if someone knowledgeable could help me, I will be forever grateful to them. Thank you. Please help me.

Comment: On another system, create a 20.10 LiveUSB installer. Boot the installer. Recover and backup your data. After your data is safe, use the installer to install 20.10 *without* erasing the disk. If your newly-installed system is unstable, then reinstall again while erasing the disk.

Comment: Can we create a 20.10 Live USB using mobile phone to do this? I only have my single laptop, mobile phone, external harddrive, USB stick and internet connection. You had advised me to take a back up earlier and I was about to take back up tomorrow and this happened today.

Comment: You can plug a USB drive into your phone?

Comment: Yes by an OTG cable, I can plug it in.

Comment: I have succeeded in creating a live bootabke USB stick with Ubuntu 20.10 using etchdrive android app and a Type C OTG cable. It took some time because my OTG cable option in phone was off. So I was not able to burn USB. Now which option should I use from a. Try Ubuntu or b. Install Ubuntu? I have an external hard drive ready to take back up of my data. Thank you.

Comment: Done. I clicked Tried Ubuntu and now I am able to access my computer's hard drive data. Already initialised back up process. While I copying, there are errors while copying and I clicked skip all. I think now I will check and verify important data and completely format the PC and reinstall everything again and put my data back in. This seems the best way for me. If anyone ever falls to this same problem and is willing to create live bootable USB, I would recommend etchdrive over ISO to USB. Etchdrive has no ad pop ups and working properly unlike ISO to USB.